# How can I get the nearest points each other in a given list in python?

Tags: python

```
from math import hypot

p = [ (0,0),(1,1),(2,3),(4,5)]
def dist(p1,p2):
    x1,y1= p1
    x2,y2= p2
    return hypot(x2-x1,y2-y1)

from itertools import combinations

distances = [dist(*pair) for pair in combinations( p,2)]
```

After this step I don't know how to do further..

Answer (score 1):

Try building a dictionary of `(pair, dist)` key-value tuples.
Then find the tuple with the minimum distance value.

```
import operator as op


pair_distances = {pair: dist(*pair) for pair in combinations(p, 2)}
min(pair_distances.items(), key=op.itemgetter(1))
#(((0, 0), (1, 1)), 1.4142135623730951)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it will be to introduce a little impurity in the function -

```
from math import hypot

p = [ (0,0),(1,1),(2,3),(4,5)]
distances = {}
def dist(p1,p2):
    x1,y1= p1
    x2,y2= p2
    distances[((x1,y1),(x2,y2))] = hypot(x2-x1,y2-y1)

from itertools import combinations

[dist(*pair) for pair in combinations( p,2)]
print(distances)

min_dist = min(distances, key=distances.get)
print("The minimum distance points are {} and {}".format(min_dist[0], min_dist[1]))
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. distances = [[dist(*pair),pair]  for pair in combinations( p,2)]
2. print sorted(distances)[0][1]
```

code line 1. define the distance list with the pair details. it will be a list of lists.

code line 2. sort the distance list. python default use the first index based sorting. therefor you will get the sorted array with distances. so [0]th element will be the smallest. [1] is its points.

This is not more accurate to do this kind of problem. but
hope this will help you